# Getting the day of the week using the corresponding number and moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying the retrieve the corresponding day of the week using moment.js

```
// e.dayOfTheWeek = 2;

let dayOfTheWeek = moment().day(e.dayOfTheWeek);

console.log(dayOfTheWeek);
```

returns the following

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Locale, _d: Tue Mar 01 2016 13:35:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)…}
```

Would like it to return `Tuesday` what am I doing wrong?

also tried `let dayOfTheWeek = moment().isoWeekday(e.dayOfTheWeek);` same result

Comment: As in documentation you need to call `moment().isoWeekday(e.dayOfTheWeek)`

Comment: `moment().isoWeekday(e.dayOfTheWeek).format('dddd')`

Comment: jcubic 's answer works ... i will accept your asnwer if you answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
moment().isoWeekday(e.dayOfTheWeek).format('dddd')
```